# How are my 用词造句 ("use the word to make a sentence") sentences using 幸福 and 俩?

Tags: grammar, hsk

In the HSK4上 Standard Course workbook, the first practice exam has this problem:

> [image: 49. An image of a bridge and groom and the word 幸福, 50. An image of a man and a woman smiling towards each other while shopping.]

It's a 用词造句 ("use the word to make a sentence") problem.  I came up with these sentences:

> 我妹妹十一月会结婚，太**幸福**了！
>   My younger sister will get married in November, too happy!
>
> 他们**俩**今天在商店一起买新衣服了。
>   Those two bought new clothes at the shop today.

I just made this up off the top of my head when sitting the practice exam, and I'm not sure what to think about my answer.

I'm hoping for a critique of the sentences, and possibly some comments as to if this is the kind of thing the examiners are looking for along with some techniques for these types of questions.

**Question**: How are my sentences?

Comment: If I was the examiner, beside grammatical correctness, I would give extra point for creativity .  I would give your sentences 90 out of 100. Grammatically, there's nothing wrong. Of course it could be written more elegantly. That requires a lot of writing practice

Comment: It is my take on the test: 49-  "弟弟終於结婚了，看他一臉幸福，我這個未嫁的姊姊真想給他一記愛的右勾拳.  50- "兩夫妻一起去買菜也笑得像去蜜月旅行一樣，所謂笨蛋情侶就是指他們這種人吧？"

Comment: I would probably write my answers as: 1. 这对新婚夫妇的脸上充满了幸福和甜蜜的笑容。2.俩情侣在商场里面相拥相偎，甚是亲昵。 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 我妹妹十一月会结婚，太
>   幸福了！
>
> 他们俩今天在商店一起买新衣服了。

Basically, both of your sentences are ok grammatically. The first one can be improved if you replace 会 with 要.

> 我妹妹十一月**要**结婚，太幸福了！

要 sounds more emotional than 会 in this context. 会 is a bit "**objective**", less **sentimental**.  In this sentence, you want to express the **excitement**(indicated by 太幸福了！), so 要 is fit better. It's like saying, 我妹妹要结婚了！ 太幸福了！！！

Answer (score 0):

Mix it up:

祝愿照片里的夫妻俩永远幸福！

他俩正在幸福地逛着商场。